# Pickview object instead of default keyboard Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement a pickview object instead of the keyboard on xamarin.ios, I found something on the net but they are not for me. I have to enter a numeric value, required on a TextField which when clicked instead of the standard keyboard will show my pickview. And it will insert it in the field to forward it afterwards to the php script for an insertion on a data base. I developed this code but I'm stuck, I humbly ask you for help :( 
Please only c# code, if you would help me.

I display the Picker with my list but when I have to go to retrieve the data and insert it somewhere for example in the Textfield or in a variable to save it and send it to the PHP script I can't get the selected value!

```
  public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        //gesture torna indietro
        var BackGesture = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(swipe);
        BackGesture.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
        BackGesture.NumberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        View.AddGestureRecognizer(BackGesture);
        //evento torna indietro
        void swipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizer sw1)
        {
            //torno indietro
            apriStoryBoard("Home");
        }
        var list = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
        ConfigurePicker(list);


       // picker.Model = colorsViewModel;

    }

    void ConfigurePicker(List<string> list)
    {
        var pickerTextField = new UITextField();
        var picker = new UIPickerView();
        picker.Model = new ColorsViewModel(list);

        var screenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        var pickerToolBar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)screenWidth, 44)) { BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default, Translucent = true };
        var flexibleSpaceButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, (sender, e) => Rips1.ResignFirstResponder());
        pickerToolBar.SetItems(new[] { flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton }, false);


         var colorsViewModel = new ColorsViewModel(list);

         colorsViewModel.ColorChange += (sender, e) =>
         {

            Rips1.Text = colorsViewModel.SelectedColor;
         };



        Rips1.InputView = picker;
        Rips1.InputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar;

    }
```

PickviewModel class:

```
class ColorsViewModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
    List<string> list;

    public event EventHandler ColorChange;
    public string SelectedColor { get; private set; }
    public override System.nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component) //non e uguale
    {
        return list.Count;
    }

    public ColorsViewModel(List<string> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public override System.nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        return list[(int)row];
    }

    //controla la selezione attuale
    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        var color = list[(int)row];

        SelectedColor = color;

        ColorChange?.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    public string getValore(nint row)
    {
        return list[(int)row];
    }

}
```

Comment: "I'm stuck" is not a helpful description of the problem.  What specifically are you stuck on?  What errors or exceptions are you getting?  If you don't want the keyboard to show, why not use a UILabel or other control instead of a UITextField?

Comment: Because I do not know how to manage them, I state that I am not very expert and I have been programming for iOS since January of this year I based myself on an idea that I see on other applications where when you perform the touch action on the TextField the pickView appears and allows you to choose from the values ​​present. The initial idea was to put a selectbox like HTML, but I didn't find anything. How would you do to manage it with the label? Would you show me some code, it could be fine anyway ...

Comment: I display the Picker with my list but when I have to go to retrieve the data and insert it somewhere for example in the Textfield or in a variable to save it and send it to the PHP script I can't get the selected value!